# How to determine main worktree from inside `.git` directory

Tags: git

How can we get the main worktree from inside a `.git` directoy taking into account env `GIT_WORKTREE` and `core.worktree`. Is this possible in a reliable way or is it impossible?
Does this solution work?

```sh
is_git_repo() {
    git -C "$1" rev-parse >/dev/null 2>&1 || return 1
}

get_main_worktree() {
    if is_git_repo "$1"; then

        if [ -n "$GIT_WORKTREE" ]; then
            echo "$GIT_WORKTREE"
        fi

        CORE_WORKTREE=$(git -C "$1" config core.worktree)
        if [ -n "$CORE_WORKTREE" ]; then
            echo "$CORE_WORKTREE"
        else
           echo "./.." # probably wrong... ?
        fi
    fi
}

cd repo/.git && get_main_worktree "."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### git worktree list --porcelain

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

I'm not sure about your references to the `.git/` directory such as cd'ing to it.  You shouldn't have to worry about the filesystem during such git operations.  git abstracts that away

Comment: You mean `git worktree list` but this cannot be invoked from the `.git` directory. We have a setup where we only know the .git dir (`--git-common-dir`...)

Comment: Ah with git 2.28 it can! perfect!