# How to find the main worktree from any worktree

Tags: git

Is there a way to determine the "main" worktree (i.e. the one with a `.git` directory) by running a command in any worktree? This does not work:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

The best I can think of is parsing `git worktree list --porcelain`, and then testing if there is a `.git` directory in each one. That seems a bit naff though. Does Git have a built in command to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Aha! It seems you can do

```
git rev-parse --path-format=absolute --git-common-dir
```

and then either just remove the `.git` from the path (probably safe) or do

```
git rev-parse --path-format=absolute --show-toplevel
```

in the directory returned from the first path.

`--path-format=absolute` is helpful because otherwise these commands sometimes return relative paths and sometimes absolute paths.

The comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64116241/265521) helped me figure this out.

Comment: That's as close as you can get. It is possible (but unusual and, if I were making the recommendation, un-recommended as well) to put the "main" worktree for some Git repository somewhere independent of the repository-proper, and in that case there's no easy way to *find* the main worktree if you don't know it.

Comment: I guess you would have to parse `git worktree list --porcelein` in that case?

Comment: But I guess maybe if you do that there is no such think as a "main" worktree...

Comment: Even that isn't *guaranteed* since someone could set all this up using the environment variable overrides and never record the right paths in any permanent file anywhere. Un-recommended. :-) (Another way to put this: [It's impossible to make anything foolproof, because fools are so ingenious.](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fgandon/miscellaneous/murphy/))

Comment: In a worktree is a file instead of directory named `.git`. It points to the worktree's `gitdir`. This command doesn't return that path. That's the one you need, for example when installing hooks in the `.git/hooks` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of a command, doing what you want, but you could parse the contents of the ".git"-File in your Worktree

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner that expands on @lukas-hankeln's answer.  It should work for most common cases.

`git rev-parse --path-format=absolute --git-common-dir | sed 's|\(.*\)/\.git|\1|'`